# Retrieving web string in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, swift3

I'm having a hard time retrieving data when I post to my web service using Swift.
All I get is the number of characters I am returning, not the actual characters. I figure they must be there, I just don't know how to retrieve them.

Here is my Swift 3 code:

```
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.nanorig.dk/api/login")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as URL)

    let bodyData = "data=something"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        print("response: \(response)")
        print("data: \(data)")
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174225400> { URL: http://www.nanorig.dk/api/login } { status code: 200, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Age = 0;
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 85;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Thu, 06 Oct 2016 13:15:18 GMT";
Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = Apache;
"Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=6so30t6brvj6j5k03kihr1m1f5; path=/";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
Via = "1.1 varnish-v4";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.26";
"X-Varnish" = 159701416;
} })
data: Optional(45 bytes)
error: nil
2016-10-06 15:15:19.428231 NanOrig[2245:1192962] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-10-06 15:15:19.436932 NanOrig[2245:1192962] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Notice, especially, the following line in the above:

```
data: Optional(45 bytes)
```

The method being run on the server is a simple PHP line:

```
echo 'just a test string to return to the swift app';
```

...this is 45 characters...

So, the way I see it, the "data" variable should somehow contain what is echoed; how else should it know the number of characters?
I just don't know how to get them out, and I have tried everything I can think of (putting the method call in a variable, assigning the data value to something else, casting it to a string, looked for a toString method, Googled and searched here for similar problems, even tried a completely different code snippet from the web, which yielded the same problem).

I have code elsewhere in my application that returns string from the server with simple GET requests, however, this needs to be a POST - I'm just not posting anything yet, since it doesn't seem to work.

I really hope someone can tell me what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to cast that Data to an `NSString` easily using `NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`.

To unwrap the resulting string (as this is a failable initialiser), do the following:

```
if let unwrappedDataString = dataString {
    // Do things with the unwrapped string.
}
```

**EDIT:**

To perfectly write this for you, use the following. Your comment had you force unwrapping data which means if for whatever reason data doesn't exist, your app will crash.

```
if let unwrappedData = data {
   if let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
          // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly after refactoring to this: NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);
It is stille returned as Optional(actual string) - do you know why that is/how to get rid of that?
I will accept your answer in 5 minutes when I'm allowed 

Comment: I have amended my answer to reflect this. ;)

Comment: That is just BEAUTIFUL! - Thank you so much, Mr. King. And it is always nice with a free bug fix 

Comment: Glad I could be of help!